# Vim key mapping for emmet-vim

Tags: vim, emmet

Ok here is what I want to accomplish:

- In `INSERT` mode I would like emmet to autocomplete with the `TAB` key

Here is what I have tried

- `let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key = '<tab>'` (Only works in `NORMAL` mode)

Though the above code is useful, I need it to work in `INSERT` mode

I am transferring over from Sublime Text to VIM and I miss having the Emmet functionality so easily accessible. Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use emmet's issue tracker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved my problem by including the following lines in my `.vimrc` file.

```
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key='<Tab>'
imap <expr> <tab> emmet#expandAbbrIntelligent("\<tab>")
```

Now I can use the `TAB` key to both indent and activate Emmet snippets in `INSERT` mode :D

Comment: Thank you! Three hours down the drain and you saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the reason for your setting not working in `INSERT` mode is because `<tab>` is mapped to something elsewhere (most likely with some auto-completion plugins). You can try to find what's mapped by `:verbose imap <tab>` when editing HTML files and disable that, but I think the simpler solution is to override the mapping yourself, like this:

```
augroup EmmetSettings
  autocmd! FileType html imap <tab> <plug>(emmet-expand-abbr)
augroup END
```

To know what is done above, see `:h autocmd` (and `:h augroup`). Basically it's telling vim to execute the specified command when editing `html` files. To know about other mappings you can use, see the [doc](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/blob/0ccaa29dbde268888be21705b0de5de89b59ef48/doc/emmet.txt#L1296).